# How do I install Oracle NoSQL Database Cloud Simulator?

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

I read about Cloud Simulator and want to install and test my applications on my computer before subscribing to the NoSQL cloud service.

I couldn't find it at the NoSQL download page. Could you please provide the steps to download and install Oracle NoSQL Database Cloud Simulator?

Answer (score 0):

You will need these requirements

- Java JDK version 10 or higher installed in your machine.
- A minimum of 5 GB available disk space where you plan to install the Oracle NoSQL Cloud Simulator.

Link to download: https://www.oracle.com/downloads/cloud/nosql-cloud-sdk-downloads.html

The steps are on the read.me file, check more info on
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/nosql-cloud/csnsd/download-oracle-nosql-cloud-simulator.html